# Use knife ssh (Chef) with interaktive mode but also initial command

Tags: ssh, knife

If I use [knife ssh](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html) like the following command I get only an interactive shell, but I want knife to open a shell initiate a command and then let me interact with it. Is this possible?

```
knife ssh "fqdn:web-1.local" interactive "apt-get update"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible [directly from knife ssh](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb#L390)

But you could use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn knife ssh "fqdn:web-1.local" interactive
send "apt-get update\r"
interact
```

You could also experiment with other backends - [screen inherits](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ssh.rb#L421) `.screenrc` from your home. Maybe it's possible to pass initial command this way.

Comment: Hm .. not exactly what I searched for, as I run the knife ssh from a Python subcommand wrapper which should "automate" processes. I look into it and try it out, thank you!